# Convexity of conditional relative entropy for Markov distributions

Tags: convexity, it.information-theory, markov-chains, entropy

Consider two Markov processes $p$ and $q$. The conditional relative entropy between them is 
\begin{align}
D(p\parallel q)& =\sum_a p(a)\sum_b p(b\mid a)\log\frac{p(b\mid a)}{q(b\mid a)}\\
& =\sum_{ab}p(ab)\log\frac{p(b\mid a)}{q(b\mid a)}
\end{align}
where $p(a)$ and $p(ab)$ are the first and second-order *stationary* distributions, respectively. I want to know: is $D$ convex in $p(ab)$?

As usual, $p(a)$ is the eigenvector of the Markov transition matrix $p$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$. The distributions are related by
$$
p(b\mid a)=\frac{p(ab)}{\sum\limits_{b'}p(ab')}=\frac{p(ab)}{p(a)}
$$

Note that $D$ can also be written
$$
D(p\parallel q)=D(p(ab)\parallel q(ab))-D(p(a)\parallel q(a))
$$
i.e. the divergence between the second-order distributions minus the divergence between the first-order distributions. Sorry for the not great notation.